# Formatting Python exception?

Tags: python, exception, formatting

I'm importing some Python modules and they will raise exception with calls like `raise TypeError(xyz)`. And now I want to change the line number of the reported exceptions if there is any.

I couldn't find the right solution on the site for my case, the one I found all required the `raise()` to be in a try and except block. With the `warnings` module I can do `warnings.formatwarning` to customize its format. Can I do the same with exception?

Comment: Why do you want to change the line number in the exception?

Comment: @KlausD. My program is a text editor. My python script will be consist of appending several scripts, the header, body, and footer. The header script would be of no interest for the users and will be hidden. So if an error was thrown, the line number reported would be wrong.

Comment: The header script will have import of modules and functions that will only be use by the program. The users will never touch them.